# How to load relational data in Firebase database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

How to load relational data in Firebase database? If one table is related to another table by foreign key then how to fetch the 2nd table records with the 1st table records from the Firebase database?

Comment: Hi Rupesh. I'm not sure what you mean by *tables* here. Firebase implements a [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) structure.

Comment: Please see the [Firebase Getting Started Guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/) and this slightly outdated but really good read [NoSQL Data Modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)